# What Tzar (Pain) is There in Leaving Egypt?

Tags: beshalach, words, yetziat-mitzrayim

It says Vayhi Beshalach Pharoh Es Haam why Vayhi that indicates a language of Tzar what Tzar(pain) is there is Leaving Mitzrayim?

Comment: From the title I thought it was a question about a Russian tzar... :)

Comment: That is Spelled Czar

Comment: No, that is actually spelled "Царь", and there are at least 4 different ways in which it can be transliterated with Latin letters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar

Comment: Why does vayhi indicate a language of tzar?

Comment: Indeed, can you source this? Why should Vayhi indicate tzar? I ask this especially because the Talmud in msh210's answer explicitly says otherwise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ohr HaChayim HaKodosh asks this question and answers that the Jews had a lot of Tzaar that Pharaoh chased them.

Another answer the Ohr HaChayim HaKodosh says is that Pharaoh escorted them out of Mitzrayim. Due to that he would get reward just as Nevochanetzar got rewarded for Sechar Pesiyos.

The Ohr HaChayim HaKodosh has other answers too.

Comment: Kol Hamarbeh banswers Hareh Zeh Mushbach

Comment: @SimchasTorah I thought it was Kol Hamarbe besources?

Answer (score 8):

The *maskana* (conclusion) of [the *g'mara* in *M'gila* 10:2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1432&size=1) is that "*vayhi*" is not always a term of pain (though "*vayhi bime*" is).